# Admob Native Express MEDIUM not work in small devices

Tags: android, admob

I have a Admob Native Express SMALL ads in my app, with dimensions in Admob 360 x 100:
[image]

in Android:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="320x100"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_native_small">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>
```

This work perfectly in all devices small or large.

Now, I want to show a Admob Native MEDIUM ads with dimension 360 x 132:
[image]

in Android:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="320x150"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_native">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>
```

This work, but only in large devices. In small devices the ads not displayed

[image]

Help me please :D